# Email all subscribers when i do an action

Tags: wp-mail, subscription, newsletter

I've created this function:

```
function email_subscribed_users($event)
{
    $users = get_users('role=subscriber');

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $accepted = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'accepted', true);
        if ($accepted) {
            wp_mail($recipients, $event->event_title, $event->event_desc, 'From: <example@example.com>');
        }
    }
}
```

But it requires a lot of time sending the emails knowing that the users will increase by time.What function should I use to send the emails efficiently or there is a newsletter plugin to do this?

Comment: Have you searched for "Newsletter Plugins"?

Comment: Careful, if you start sending out a ton of unsolicited mail from your domain you're going to get blacklisted.  You're much better off using a service like aweber, mailchimp, etc.

Comment: Yes @Howdy_McGee i searched but the plugins send emails when a new post or a new page is published.The problem is that i've created a section called "events" and it's neither post or page it simply uses $wpdb thats why I need a function to do that :/

Comment: What newsletter plugin does what i want do you know any?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly query for users having a specific user_meta value. This will gain some performance over loading all the users first and then iterating over them and loading the meta_value afterwards.

Have a look at the [WP_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) class.

---

If we are speaking of larger numbers of mails you may be better off to use a full-blown newsletter plugin (that will automatically queue the mails and not try to send them all at once). And if you are really sending a lot of mails (like +5.000 in one newsletter) I would advise you to use an external mail service provider (CakeMail, Mailchimp ...).

Comment: if there is no personalization done in the mail you might be able to save time by sending it to multiple recipients by using BCC.

Comment: I used Wysija newsletter but i don't know how to send emails "programmatically" when i call my own function send_emails().That is what I want can I do that with Wysija or any other newsletter?

Comment: @AntonioPapa Actually Wysija already adds jobs to wp-cron itself to shedule the emails in batches (like 50 mails per cron run), so you might have a look at that, maybe you are able to create those cronjobs by yourself to make it send emails at regular intervals (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/ is a great plugin for looking which jobs are sheduled).